# Java - Asking user if they want to continue (only accepting 'y' or 'n')

Tags: java

This is my first time posting on here, so if it is formatted poorly I apologize. My application is meant to ask the user to enter one of my roomates name, and the application will output information about that roomate. Then, it should ask the user if it wants to continue. I want it to only be able to accept 'y' or 'n'. When it asks if I want to continue, I enter a letter other than 'y' or 'n' and it correctly asks me to enter an acceptable answer. However, if I DO enter 'y' or 'n' it acts as if I entered an unacceptable answer ONLY ONE TIME, and THEN does what it is supposed to do. Any help is very appreciated.

```
package roomateapp;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class RoomateApp {


public static void main(String[] args) {



    //Initialize scanner to take in roomate name
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cont = "y";
    while (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

//CODE HERE BUT NOT SHOWN

        //Ask to continue
        System.out.println("Would you like to continue? (y/n)");
        cont = sc.next();
        System.out.println();

        if (!cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || !cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            while (!cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || !cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

                System.out.println("Please enter 'y' or 'n'");
                System.out.println("Would you like to continue? (y/n)");
                cont = sc.next();
                if (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Every possible string is either not "y" or not "n".

Comment: Why do you have *two* while loops and another *two* if statements that all check the typed value. Try reducing complexity. I this that one while loop with the `cont = sc.next()` call in the beginnning should be sufficient. And besides the last `break` statement in the end is superflous, because in this case the next while loop would end anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As @shmosel mentioned in their comment:

```
if (!cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || !cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
```

will always be true - using boolean logic, we can tell it is equivalent to

`if (!(cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n")))`

which may make it clearer that it is always true.

You probably want to check that it is *neither* "y" nor "n", which you could write as:

```
if (!(cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n")))
```

Or equivalently:

```
if (!cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
```

If you want to learn more about why the above are equivalent, check out the Wikipedia page on [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (which relate to this particular equivalence) or the page on [Logical Equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) more generally

Comment: Thank you! I had actually tried it in a less complex manner (without the if loop) and was still getting the same result. However, it worked when I put if (!cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n")). I am still pretty new to coding so I make some dumb mistakes but that makes sense now that I think about it.

Comment: No worries - if this answer (or some other answer) has solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer (checkmark to the top left of the answer) so that others know this question has been resolved for you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check that you have "y" or "n", instead of checking what you don't have?.

I would initialize `cont` to `null` or some other sentinel value, and then loop while `cont` remains unchanged. I would only assign a value to `cont`, once you have validated inside of the loop that the value given by the user is either "y" or "n".

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Would you like to continue? (y/n)");

    String cont = null;
    while(cont == null) {
        String unvalidatedString = sc.next();
        if (unvalidatedString.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            cont = unvalidatedString;
            break;
        }
        if (unvalidatedString.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            cont = unvalidatedString;
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter 'y' or 'n'");
    }

    // This is just added as a test case for you to verify that it's working. Remove from production code. 
    System.out.printf("The value of cont is: %s\n", cont);
```